# POST requests with EmberData and Django REST Framework

Tags: django, ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework, json-api

I am integrating a `django-rest-framework` backend and an `Ember` frontend (with `EmberData`). These are my versions:

- Django 1.9
- djangorestframework 3.3.2
- django-rest-framework-json-api ([latest version](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api) from github)
- ember-cli 1.13.13
- ember 2.2.0
- ember-data 2.2.1

`GET` requests are working fine, but `POST`s are not. This is the kind of request coming from `EmberData`:

```
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "name": "The project name",
      "description": "The project description",
      "price": 123
    },
    "relationships": {
      "onwer": {
        "data": null
      }
    },
    "type": "projects"
  }
}
```

But django is crashing, and reporting:

```
Page not found ... The current URL, api/projects, didn't match any of these
```

My URLs are created with a router:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from .viewsets.projects import ProjectViewSet


router = DefaultRouter()
...
router.register(r'projects', ProjectViewSet)
...
```

and `ViewSet`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import filters

from vwrks.models import Project

from ..serializers import ProjectSerializer

class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing Project instances.
    """
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter)
    filter_fields = ('seller', 'artist', 'subcategory')
    search_fields = ('name', 'description')
```

According to the documentation (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset), `ViewSet`s provide support for `.create()`, so this POST operation should be supported.

I have also tweaked the trailing slashes for Django, in order to accept `POST`s at `/projects` as `EmberData` is doing (besides the default `/projects/` that Django is expecting)

```
# EmberData does POST to /projects (not /projects/), so we need this:
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

The problem that I see is that `Django`'s router does not generate a `project-create` URL (only `project-list` and `project-detail` are listed):

```
^api/ ^projects/$ [name='project-list']
^api/ ^projects\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='project-list']
^api/ ^projects/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='project-detail']
^api/ ^projects/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='project-detail']
```

What can I do to get `POST`s requests from `EmberData` to `drf` working?

Comment: project-list with POST method will call create()

Comment: @GeoJacob: That's what I thought too, but then, why the "Page not found ... The current URL, api/projects, didn't match any of these"

Comment: @GeoJacob: could it be that, even though django has a flag `APPEND_SLASH`, this is not taken into account by the `DefaultRouter`? It is adding the trailing slash anyway!

Comment: @GeoJacob: so, I think I found it. I managed to miss the trailing_slash config parameter for the router (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter). Apparently for drf `APPEND_SLASH` is not relevant

Answer (score 4):

Do not pay attention to the Django message:

```
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8080/api/projects/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
```

The relevant system is the [DRF's router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter), which is not affected by `APPEND_SLASH`. You need to remove the trailing slash with:

```
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
```